# Free amalgated product and injectivity (using universal property)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider the following commutative diagram of group homomorphisms ( I know it looks ugly):
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
     &  & G_1 & \\
    & \nearrow{i_1} &  & \searrow{f_1} & \\
   A &  &  &  & G 
\\
    & \searrow{i_2} &  & \nearrow{f_2} & \\
    &  & G_2 & 
    \end{array}
$$

here $i_1,i_2$ are injective. We say that $G$ is the amlagated product $G_1*_A G_2$ if for any pair of homomorphisms $\phi_i:G_i\to H$ with $\phi_1 \circ i_1=\phi_2 \circ i_2$ there exists a unique homomorphism $\phi:G\to H$ such that $\phi \circ f_i=\phi_i$.

I want to show that then the composition $f_1 \circ i_1$ is injecetive, using the universal property above.

I already know how to show it using the explicit construction of $G$ as a quotient of $G_1 *G_2$, but I was not able to mimic the proof.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2324/how-to-draw-a-commutative-diagram You can't do diagonal arrows with AMScd, but that should be fine enough for this example (just rotate it 45 degrees clockwise).

Comment: Are you sure it is $\phi\circ i_i=\phi_i$ and not $f_i$ instead of $i_i$?.

Comment: In general, one can ask if there is a conceptual way to prove that colimits are 'large' (that they are small, i.e. generated by the images of the arrows to it, follows from the universal property). I don't know if there is. It seems that we always need to rely on the explicit construction. (E.g.: why is the dimension of the tensor product of vector spaces at least the product of the dimensions? Why is the polynomial ring $R[X]$ strictly larger than $R$?)

Comment: @Javi, you are right, I will fix it

Comment: @barto: what do you mean with "large"

Comment: @klirk It depends on the situation. In the case of polynomial rings, we expect that $R[X]$ is strictly larger than $R$, or for example that $X$ is not a zero divisor. In a free group on two letters, we expect there to be no relation between the variables, except trivial ones. In the tensor product of vector spaces with bases $(e_i)$ and $(f_j)$, we expect the $e_i \otimes f_j$ to be linearly independent., etc etc. In this question, we want $G$ to at least contain a copy of $A$.