# Is it always possible to take $H$ such that $\phi_1$ is injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I was trying to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2844695/free-amalgated-product-and-injectivity-using-universal-property/2844722#2844722) in a way that it was sufficient to take $H$ such that $\phi_1$ could be chosen to be injective. At first I thought of taking $H=G_1$ and $\phi_1=id_{G_1}$, but I don't know how to define $\phi_2$ in a way such that $\phi_1\circ i_1=\phi_2\circ i_2$.

I don't know if this is even possible, so can I always choose such $H$?

Answer (score 2):

Taking $\phi_1=id_{G_1}$ does not work in general.

If we take $i_1=id_A$, then the condition on the homomorphisms reduces to $id_{A_1}=\phi_2 \circ i_2$. But this means that $i_2$ has to admit a left inverse.

If $i_2:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$, $1\mapsto 2$, then there is no left inverse.

Remark/abstract nonsense: In the example I used that $\mathbb Z $ is not divisible. Divisble abelian groups are exactly the injective abelian groups and being injective is a necessary condition on the group $G_2$ if we want $\phi_1$ to be the identity.

Comment: Thanks. So even if I tried to find another $H$ and $\phi_1$, in general I won't be able to do it, right?

Comment: I am not sure about that. I am only saying that taking $\phi_1=Id$ does not work. I tried this strategy of finding the right $H$ an $\phi_i$ as well before asking the linked question. So far I did not come up with anything useful. $H=G_1 *G_2$ is also not possible